# two json file in jquery one for taking data values and other for data types

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use two json file. One for taking the data type of data and other for getting the data value of data.
Since I don’t know how to use two json file in one so I stored one json values in a variable.

```
 var data = {
 “name”: “classxyz”,
 “number”:”abc”,
 Fields : [
    {
 “name”: ”studentname”,
 “marks”:”int”
 “doc”: “failed”
  }
   ]
}
```

Second json file “student.json”

```
{
“datasvalue”:
[
{
 “studentname”: “Jack”,
 “marks”: “18”,
 “place”: “newyork”
},
{
 “studentname”: “sparrow”,
 “marks”: “12”,
 “place”: “london”
}
]
}
```

I want to take the value of data type from the first json and check it into the second json and then show the value of that data type which is taken in first json.
Example: From the first json I search name is “studentname” and now I want to print this “studentname” as a label and search it in the second json file (student.json) and  print its value(sparrow) in front of studentname in textfield.
When I print the “marks” it should check from the first json file that it has “int” type and search its value from student.json value that is 18. If I try to put any other value it should not let me enter.

So far, I am able to do the following which is far away from what I have to do.

Can’t we use two json in one program? And why the .inArray is not working this way?

```
 function ViewData()
 {
   function toArray(obj) {
          var result = [];
            for (var key2 in obj) {
            var value = obj[key2];
            result.push(key2);
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                      result.push(toArray(value));
                } else {
                    result.push(value);
                }
                $('#stage').append('<p>'+ key2+'  : '+ "<input id=\"txtv\" type=\"text\" value=\""+value+"\"/>"); 
             }  
        return result;
    }
        var arra =[];
    arra = JSON.strigify(toArray(data));
    $('#stage1').html('<p>'+arra + "<br>"+'</p>');
    //$('#stage1':contains('day'));
  }
    $.getJSON('student.json',
        function(datas)
        {
           // Create an array to hold the data.
            var items = [];
            var storeName=[];
            var storeValue=[];
           // Parse the data by looking at each entry in the dates object.
            $.each(datas.datasvalue,
               function(key1, value1)
                 {  
                    var i=0;
                    $.each(value1, function(key,value){
                    storeName[i]= key;
                    storeValue[i] = value;               
                    $('#stage2').each(function(){
                //      if($.inArray(key.text(),arra)){
                            alert($.inArray(key,arra));
                            $(this).append('<p>'+ key+'  : '+ "<input id=\"txtv\" type=\"text\" value=\""+value+"\"/>");
                    //  }

                    }); // end of stage each funtion              
                    i++;
                }); // end of value and key funtion
            }); // end of value1 function    
          }); // end of function (data)
```

Comment: That's pretty complicated.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Not feeling stupid anymore :)I am doing something complicated :)

Comment: Ha ha!  Yeah -- been there / done that.  Sometimes making things complete is making them too complex.  You might be able to shave off a lot of code and complexity by just hard-coding the schema.  Or re-structuring your data.  For example, is this how you would do it if the data was in a database?  Sorry.

Comment: unfortunately i can't change the data structure :(
I have to do this way.